# Ignite Cache operations get stuck when multiple thin clients try to perform CRUD operations in parallel with partition map exchange

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Looks like partition map exchange process and cache CRUD operations in parallel are causing deadlock or lock acquire failures.

What should be the strategy to handle this scenario ?

Ignite server has below errors:

**Exception stack trace 1:**

```
WARNING: Dumping the near node thread that started transaction [xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705217, nodeOrder=1], nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84]
Stack trace of the transaction owner thread:
Thread [name="client-connector-#56%perf-dn1%", id=93, state=WAITING, blockCnt=5023, waitCnt=36165]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:304)
        at o.a.i.i.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:178)
        at o.a.i.i.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:141)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$41.op(GridCacheAdapter.java:3430)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$41.op(GridCacheAdapter.java:3423)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.syncOp(GridCacheAdapter.java:4480)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.remove0(GridCacheAdapter.java:3423)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.remove(GridCacheAdapter.java:3405)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.remove(GridCacheAdapter.java:3388)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.remove(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1438)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.remove(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:964)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.platform.client.cache.ClientCacheRemoveKeyRequest.process(ClientCacheRemoveKeyRequest.java:41)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.platform.client.ClientRequestHandler.handle(ClientRequestHandler.java:77)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:204)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:55)
        at o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:279)
        at o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
        at o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter$3.body(GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter.java:97)
        at o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorkerPool$1.run(GridWorkerPool.java:70)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Exception stack trace 2:**

```
WARNING: >>> Transaction [startTime=11:39:27.214, curTime=11:40:36.277, systemTime=0, userTime=69063, tx=GridNearTxLocal [mappings=IgniteTxMappingsImpl [], nearLocallyMapped=false, colocatedLocallyMapped=false, needCheckBackup=null, hasRemoteLocks=false, trackTimeout=false, systemTime=44700, systemStartTime=0, prepareStartTime=0, prepareTime=0, commitOrRollbackStartTime=0, commitOrRollbackTime=0, lb=null, mvccOp=null, qryId=-1, crdVer=0, thread=client-connector-#57%perf-dn1%, mappings=IgniteTxMappingsImpl [], super=GridDhtTxLocalAdapter [nearOnOriginatingNode=false, span=o.a.i.i.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@4a931268, nearNodes=KeySetView [], dhtNodes=KeySetView [], explicitLock=false, super=IgniteTxLocalAdapter [completedBase=null, sndTransformedVals=false, depEnabled=false, txState=IgniteTxStateImpl [activeCacheIds=[], recovery=null, mvccEnabled=null, mvccCachingCacheIds=[], txMap=EmptySet []], super=IgniteTxAdapter [xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705226, nodeOrder=1], writeVer=null, implicit=false, loc=true, threadId=95, startTime=1635853167214, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, timeout=0, sysInvalidate=false, sys=false, plc=2, commitVer=null, finalizing=NONE, invalidParts=null, state=SUSPENDED, timedOut=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], mvccSnapshot=null, skipCompletedVers=false, parentTx=null, duration=69079ms, onePhaseCommit=false], size=0]]]]
Nov 2, 2021 11:40:36 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger warning
WARNING: First 10 long running cache futures [total=16]
Nov 2, 2021 11:40:36 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger warning
WARNING: >>> Future [startTime=11:39:27.324, curTime=11:40:36.277, fut=GridDhtLockFuture [span=o.a.i.i.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@4a931268, nearNodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, nearLockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], threadId=124, futId=be58a60ec71-1d64903c-c700-4deb-bace-cc5158713120, lockVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1], read=false, err=null, timedOut=false, timeout=0, tx=GridNearTxLocal [mappings=IgniteTxMappingsImpl []dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]]], prepared=0, locked=false, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, locMapped=false, expiryPlc=null, transferExpiryPlc=false, flags=2, partUpdateCntr=0, serReadVer=null, xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1]]]], super=IgniteTxAdapter [xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1], writeVer=null, implicit=false, loc=true, threadId=124, startTime=1635853167214, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, timeout=0, sysInvalidate=false, sys=false, plc=2, commitVer=null, finalizing=NONE, invalidParts=null, state=ACTIVE, timedOut=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], mvccSnapshot=null, skipCompletedVers=false, parentTx=null, duration=69094ms, onePhaseCommit=false], size=1]], nearLocallyMapped=false, colocatedLocallyMapped=true, needCheckBackup=null, hasRemoteLocks=false, trackTimeout=false, systemTime=75000, systemStartTime=971108549857700, prepareStartTime=0, prepareTime=0, commitOrRollbackStartTime=0, commitOrRollbackTime=0, lb=null, mvccOp=null, qryId=-1, crdVer=0, thread=client-connector-#84%perf-dn1%, mappings=IgniteTxMappingsImpl []dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]]], prepared=0, locked=false, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, locMapped=false, expiryPlc=null, transferExpiryPlc=false, flags=2, partUpdateCntr=0, serReadVer=null, xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1]]]], super=IgniteTxAdapter [xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1], writeVer=null, implicit=false, loc=true, threadId=124, startTime=1635853167214, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, timeout=0, sysInvalidate=false, sys=false, plc=2, commitVer=null, finalizing=NONE, invalidParts=null, state=ACTIVE, timedOut=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], mvccSnapshot=null, skipCompletedVers=false, parentTx=null, duration=69094ms, onePhaseCommit=false], size=1]], super=GridDhtTxLocalAdapter [nearOnOriginatingNode=false, span=o.a.i.i.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@4a931268, nearNodes=KeySetView [], dhtNodes=KeySetView [], explicitLock=false, super=IgniteTxLocalAdapter [completedBase=null, sndTransformedVals=false, depEnabled=false, txState=IgniteTxStateImpl [activeCacheIds=[585748697], recovery=false, mvccEnabled=false, mvccCachingCacheIds=[], txMap=ArrayList [IgniteTxEntry [txKey=IgniteTxKey [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], cacheId=585748697], val=TxEntryValueHolder [val=null, op=DELETE], prevVal=TxEntryValueHolder [val=null, op=NOOP], oldVal=TxEntryValueHolder [val=null, op=NOOP], entryProcessorsCol=null, ttl=-1, conflictExpireTime=-1, conflictVer=null, explicitVer=null, dhtVer=null, filters=CacheEntryPredicate[] [], filtersPassed=false, filtersSet=true, entry=GridDhtCacheEntry [rdrs=ReaderId[] [], part=244, super=GridDistributedCacheEntry [super=GridCacheMapEntry [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], val=null, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705229, nodeOrder=1], hash=1085684290, extras=GridCacheMvccEntryExtras [mvcc=GridCacheMvcc [locs=LinkedList [GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705207, nodeOrder=1], threadId=122, id=2104, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], reentry=null, otherNodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, otherVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705207, nodeOrder=1], mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=1|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null], GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1], threadId=124, id=2102, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], reentry=null, otherNodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, otherVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1], mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null], GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705213, nodeOrder=1], threadId=122, id=2120, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], reentry=null, otherNodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, otherVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705213, nodeOrder=1], mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705207, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null], GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705214, nodeOrder=1], threadId=123, id=2118, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], reentry=null, otherNodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, otherVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705214, nodeOrder=1], mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705207, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null], GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705217, nodeOrder=1], threadId=93, id=2108, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], reentry=null, otherNodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, otherVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705217, nodeOrder=1], mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null], GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705218, nodeOrder=1], threadId=115, id=2106, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], reentry=null, otherNodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, otherVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705218, nodeOrder=1], mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null], GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705222, nodeOrder=1], threadId=95, id=2110, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], reentry=null, otherNodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, otherVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705222, nodeOrder=1], mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null], GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705223, nodeOrder=1], threadId=120, id=2112, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], reentry=null, otherNodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, otherVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705223, nodeOrder=1], mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null], GridCacheMvccCandidate [nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705227, nodeOrder=1], threadId=118, id=2114, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], reentry=null, otherNodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, otherVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705227, nodeOrder=1], mappedDhtNodes=null, mappedNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]]]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]]], prepared=0, locked=false, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, locMapped=false, expiryPlc=null, transferExpiryPlc=false, flags=2, partUpdateCntr=0, serReadVer=null, xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1]]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]]], prepared=0, locked=false, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, locMapped=false, expiryPlc=null, transferExpiryPlc=false, flags=2, partUpdateCntr=0, serReadVer=null, xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1]]]]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]]], prepared=0, locked=false, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, locMapped=false, expiryPlc=null, transferExpiryPlc=false, flags=2, partUpdateCntr=0, serReadVer=null, xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1]]]], super=IgniteTxAdapter [xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1], writeVer=null, implicit=false, loc=true, threadId=124, startTime=1635853167214, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, timeout=0, sysInvalidate=false, sys=false, plc=2, commitVer=null, finalizing=NONE, invalidParts=null, state=ACTIVE, timedOut=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], mvccSnapshot=null, skipCompletedVers=false, parentTx=null, duration=69094ms, onePhaseCommit=false], size=1]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]]], prepared=0, locked=false, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, locMapped=false, expiryPlc=null, transferExpiryPlc=false, flags=2, partUpdateCntr=0, serReadVer=null, xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1]]]], super=IgniteTxAdapter [xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1], writeVer=null, implicit=false, loc=true, threadId=124, startTime=1635853167214, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, timeout=0, sysInvalidate=false, sys=false, plc=2, commitVer=null, finalizing=NONE, invalidParts=null, state=ACTIVE, timedOut=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], mvccSnapshot=null, skipCompletedVers=false, parentTx=null, duration=69094ms, onePhaseCommit=false], size=1]]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]]], prepared=0, locked=false, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, locMapped=false, expiryPlc=null, transferExpiryPlc=false, flags=2, partUpdateCntr=0, serReadVer=null, xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1]]]], super=IgniteTxAdapter [xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1], writeVer=null, implicit=false, loc=true, threadId=124, startTime=1635853167214, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, timeout=0, sysInvalidate=false, sys=false, plc=2, commitVer=null, finalizing=NONE, invalidParts=null, state=ACTIVE, timedOut=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], mvccSnapshot=null, skipCompletedVers=false, parentTx=null, duration=69094ms, onePhaseCommit=false], size=1]]]dNearNodes=null, ownerVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705211, nodeOrder=1], serOrder=null, key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true], masks=local=1|owner=0|ready=1|reentry=0|used=0|tx=1|single_implicit=0|dht_local=1|near_local=0|removed=0|read=0, prevVer=null, nextVer=null]], rmts=null]], flags=3]]], prepared=0, locked=false, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, locMapped=false, expiryPlc=null, transferExpiryPlc=false, flags=2, partUpdateCntr=0, serReadVer=null, xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1]]]], super=IgniteTxAdapter [xidVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247332659, order=1635852705208, nodeOrder=1], writeVer=null, implicit=false, loc=true, threadId=124, startTime=1635853167214, nodeId=2735bef0-7404-41e3-843f-7043490c9d84, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, timeout=0, sysInvalidate=false, sys=false, plc=2, commitVer=null, finalizing=NONE, invalidParts=null, state=ACTIVE, timedOut=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=162], mvccSnapshot=null, skipCompletedVers=false, parentTx=null, duration=69094ms, onePhaseCommit=false], size=1]]], mapped=false, trackable=true, createTtl=-1, accessTtl=-1, needReturnVal=false, skipStore=false, keepBinary=true, innerFuts=EmptyList [], pendingLocks=HashSet [KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=244, val=data=6ff0c60ec71-625345be-9a91-497a-895e-abbe5df9da3d], hasValBytes=true]], super=GridCompoundIdentityFuture [super=GridCompoundFuture [rdc=Bool reducer: true, initFlag=0, lsnrCalls=0, done=false, cancelled=false, err=null, futs=EmptyList []]]]]
Nov 2, 2021 11:40:36 AM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger warning
```

**Exception stack trace 3 when TxTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange is set to some value**

```
Nov 2, 2021 1:11:19 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger warning
WARNING: The transaction was forcibly rolled back on partition map exchange because a timeout is reached: [tx=GridNearTxLocal[xid=e0e3db0ec71-00000000-0ebe-146c-0000-000000000001, xidVersion=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247338092, order=1635858071054, nodeOrder=1], nearXidVersion=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247338092, order=1635858071054, nodeOrder=1], concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, state=ACTIVE, invalidate=false, rollbackOnly=false, nodeId=1ed7077a-5547-41c1-94ab-d246944ed4a9, timeout=0, startTime=1635858659324, duration=20140, label=null], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=104]]
Nov 2, 2021 1:11:19 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed to process client request [req=o.a.i.i.processors.platform.client.cache.ClientCacheRemoveKeyRequest@2fea4a3]
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.transactions.TransactionRollbackException: Failed to finish transaction because it has been rolled back [timeout=0, tx=GridNearTxLocal[xid=f0e3db0ec71-00000000-0ebe-146c-0000-000000000001, xidVersion=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247338092, order=1635858071055, nodeOrder=1], nearXidVersion=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247338092, order=1635858071055, nodeOrder=1], concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, state=ACTIVE, invalidate=false, rollbackOnly=false, nodeId=1ed7077a-5547-41c1-94ab-d246944ed4a9, timeout=0, startTime=1635858659324, duration=20140, label=null]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1266)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.cacheException(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:2084)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.remove(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1441)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.remove(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:964)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.client.cache.ClientCacheRemoveKeyRequest.process(ClientCacheRemoveKeyRequest.java:41)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.client.ClientRequestHandler.handle(ClientRequestHandler.java:77)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:204)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:55)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:279)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter$3.body(GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter.java:97)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorkerPool$1.run(GridWorkerPool.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.transactions.TransactionRollbackException: Failed to finish transaction because it has been rolled back [timeout=0, tx=GridNearTxLocal[xid=f0e3db0ec71-00000000-0ebe-146c-0000-000000000001, xidVersion=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247338092, order=1635858071055, nodeOrder=1], nearXidVersion=GridCacheVersion [topVer=247338092, order=1635858071055, nodeOrder=1], concurrency=PESSIMISTIC, isolation=REPEATABLE_READ, state=ACTIVE, invalidate=false, rollbackOnly=false, nodeId=1ed7077a-5547-41c1-94ab-d246944ed4a9, timeout=0, startTime=1635858659324, duration=20140, label=null]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$11.apply(IgniteUtils.java:974)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$11.apply(IgniteUtils.java:972)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the [expected behavior](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/transactions#long-running-transactions-termination):

> When the partition map exchange starts, Ignite acquires a global lock
> at a particular stage. The lock can’t be obtained while incomplete
> transactions are running in parallel. These transactions prevent the
> partition map exchange process from moving forward​, thus, blocking
> some operations such as a new node join process.

In other words, PME process should wait until the end of all active transactions to acquire a global lock. Therefore it's recommended to:

- either set a global TX timeout (`TransactionConfiguration#DefaultTxTimeout`) or configure it individually for every transaction, i.e. make sure that you are not running it forever in a worst-case scenario.
- configure `TxTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange` to be non zero (default).

The concrete numbers are individual, but I suppose mostly you'd like to have a lower timeout on PME in comparison to a "normal" TX timeout for quicker cluster-wide updates.

Comment: I have more than 25 thin clients on different VMs which are continuously performing CRUD operations on same AND/OR different caches from ignite db. So there are continuous transactions being opened and closed and in between some new caches are also getting created.  Configuring TxTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange is always advisable?

Comment: Well, if you won't specify it and something went wrong (a TX freeze or whatever) you might end up with a stuck cluster and manual resolution like TX kill or a node restart might be required. Therefore I'd say - yes, TxTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange will save your time.

Comment: Just in case - cache creation/destroy are cluster-wide procedures and trigger PME as well.

Comment: Thanks Alexandr ! What if my thin clients starts the continuous transactional CRUD operations as soon as it connects to the cluster, and meanwhile other clients are also creating the caches, in that case there will always be the race between ongoing transactions and cache creation. Even if we introduce timeouts, it will again go into the same problem as few clients are continuously trying to perform transactional CRUD and few clients are trying to create caches and PME is getting triggered.